# weakly compact in metric space

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

We know a Borel probability measure $m$ on a complete
metric space $X$ is a Radon measure if and only if there
exists a separable subset $Y \in B(X)$ (Borel subset of $X$) such that $m(Y)=1$.

Now, if  $X$ is a weakly compact set in a Banach space and $m$ is a Radon measure on it, is there a separable subset $Y \in B(X)$ (Borel subset of $X$) such that $m(Y)=1$?